# trace cotrace Matrix

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, terminology, finite-fields

Hello I want to know whats mean (trace) cotrace matrix.

In the context, mapping a matrix (t x n) $\in$ GF($2^m$) to a cotrace matrix (tm x n) $\in$ GF($2$)?

Comment: You would have a much better chance of getting an answer if you said where you had come across this term.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean *trace parity-check matrix* and *co-trace parity-check matrix*, as defined in  the context of error-correcting codes, see definition 6 of [Compact McEliece Keys from Goppa Codes](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/187.pdf), or see page 2 of [arXiv:1302.5081](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5081.pdf).